# History Sensitive Back Button

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to have a button on a webpage that will be named 'Back' and do window.history.back() if the user has navigated to the page from another page on your website and otherwise have some other title and be a direct link if the user navigated to your page from another website or went to the page directly.

Google plus on mobile seems to have this behaviour. When you click on a post in your stream then it has a 'back' button on the post page. However, if you go to the post page directly then it has a 'stream' button on the post page.

This seems tricky to implement because you don't have access to the urls in window.history.

Comment: Searching for "manipulate browser history JavaScript" showed some interesting results. Here's a link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: You have access to the referrer - page they came from. `document.referrer`

Comment: thanks. that's exactly what i wanted

Comment: actually, i'm using ajax navigation with query fragments so this won't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you any chance of adding an ext lib like [BBQ](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html)? It's a package used to manage the history behavior in your page.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before. You can do this with an anchor in the link. The anchor needs to have every get parameter of your application (i.e. application state) stored. Your application should be able to parse the anchor. To intercept the back button look here: stackoverflow.com/questions/136937/is-there-a-way-to-catch-the-back-button-event-in-javascript.

Answer (score -1):

@benmmurphy I also had the same problem, then I used the following, which worked perfectly for me. You have to paste it on the page, from where you want to go back.

```
<a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">GO BACK</a>
```

Hope this will help you.